# How do I find out why my RabbitMQ connection is failing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, rabbitmq

I've been banging my head against a wall for a couple of days on this one.

I have a very basic rabbitMQ service set up in docker. I can write a simple console app to write to and read from this service. I can also access the rabbitMQ web portal no problem.

However, when I try to use it from inside a fairly complex web app I'm working on, it fails every time on the `factory.CreateConnection()` method with the `None of the specified endpoints were reachable` error. My first thought was that there was an issue when accessing from IISExpress. So, I tried the following to determine where I'm going wrong:

- Try from inside a fresh MVC ASP app - this worked.
- Try from inside a fresh MVC ASP app with SSL switched on - this worked.

So now I know it works in console, and it works through IISExpress with and without SSL. I then tried the following in the *failing* app (spoiler, none of these worked):

- Move the `CreateConnection()` code outside the constructor so it's not instantiated by Ninject.
- Set loopback_users to none in the config file.
- Create new users (both through the web portal and in definitions.json) with varying levels of authority and use them in the connection method.
- Create new vhosts for the new users and try to connect with and without them.
- Change the timeout.

In every case I get the same result. When going through the working apps (with identical code) I get this result in the output:

```
rabbitMQTest_1  | 2020-08-21 16:24:28.820 [info] <0.11124.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.11124.0> (198.19.0.1:57186 -> 198.19.0.2:5672)
rabbitMQTest_1  | 2020-08-21 16:24:28.899 [info] <0.11124.0> connection <0.11124.0> (198.19.0.1:57186 -> 198.19.0.2:5672): user 'testuser' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'test-vhost'
rabbitMQTest_1  | 2020-08-21 16:24:28.983 [info] <0.11124.0> closing AMQP connection <0.11124.0> (198.19.0.1:57186 -> 198.19.0.2:5672, vhost: 'test-vhost', user: 'testuser')
```

When trying through the failing app, I get this instead:

```
rabbitMQTest_1  | 2020-08-21 16:26:30.640 [info] <0.11354.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.11354.0> (198.19.0.1:57202 -> 198.19.0.2:5672)
rabbitMQTest_1  | 2020-08-21 16:26:40.613 [error] <0.11354.0> closing AMQP connection <0.11354.0> (198.19.0.1:57202 -> 198.19.0.2:5672):
rabbitMQTest_1  | {handshake_timeout,frame_header}
```

The only difference left between the working and non-working apps is that the latter has a security sign in and authentication via an in-house application.

For reference, this is my docker.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rabbitMQTest:
    image: rabbitmq-local
    hostname: localhost
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 15672:15672
    - 5672:5672
```

My Docker file:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management
ADD rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/
ADD definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq/
RUN chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
CMD ["rabbitmq-server"]
```

My config file:

```
loopback_users = none

# IPv4
listeners.tcp.default = 5672

## HTTP listener and embedded Web server settings.
management.tcp.port = 15672

# Load queue definitions
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json

#Ignore SSL
ssl_options.verify               = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = true
```

and here's the bog-standard C# code used to connect and write to rabbitMQ:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", UserName = "testuser", Password = "testpassword", VirtualHost = "test-vhost"};
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare("MyExchange", "direct", true);
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "MyQueue",
                                 durable: true,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);
            channel.QueueBind("MyQueue", "MyExchange", "routingKey");
         
            var message = "Howdy";
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                 routingKey: "routingKey", 
                                 basicProperties: null,
                                 body: body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Send {0}", message);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As I said, the only difference I can think of now is that my non-working app has this in-house authentication that the others don't. I don't know if that makes a difference. What I need to do now is dig deeper. Does anyone know of a way to get some more logging information from rabbitMQ? In particular, what's happening in that 10 seconds where the handshake just refuses to take hold? The fact that it just drops without any info is driving me nuts!

Alternatively, if someone just straight out has the answer to this one, I would be beyond grateful!

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering this one myself. Maybe this can help someone out who lands in a similar problem.

The problem is the versions of the dlls that RabbitMQ relies on. I noticed that my app had slightly different versions. By doing a binding redirect to the ones RabbitMQ relies on, I fixed the issue.

Comment: Any specifics? Examples?